# Arbitrary analogue of increasing sequence of sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\Lambda$ be any arbitrary index set and $X=\cup_{\alpha\in\Lambda}X_\alpha$. Find the condition on the collection $\{X_\alpha : \alpha\in\Lambda\}$ so that if $F$ is any finite subset of $X$, then $F\subseteq X_\alpha$ for some $\alpha\in\Lambda$.

I have obsersved that the quention can be answered easily for any countable index set. As for example, if $X=\cup_{n\in\mathbb N}X_n$ and if $X_i\subseteq X_j$ for any $1\leq i<j$, then the required condition is satisfied. I am searching for similar condition in case of arbitrary index collection.

Comment: One such condition is "$X_\alpha = X$ for all $\alpha\in\Lambda$". If that isn't sufficient, what properties do you require the condition to have?

Comment: @GregMartin It is possibe to consider a countable collection $\{X_n : n\in\mathbb N\}$ such that $X_i\subseteq X_j$ for any $1\leq i< j$. Is it possible to consider  such type of arbitrary collection?

Comment: For that one would need a total ordering on $\Lambda$, which is certainly possible to arrange.

Answer (score 2):

One easy way to get to an answer is to start by taking any set $X$, and simply looking at the simplest (but not trivial) collection of sets which guarantee that every finite subset of $X$ will be a subset of some element in the collection: simply take *all* finite subsets of $X$.

This is not linearly ordered set, and it's easy to see that if $X$ is uncountable, we can't even find a cofinal linear order (that is, given any chain of finite subsets, there will be some finite set disjoint from all of them).

But what property do the finite subsets of $X$ do have? Well, the union of two finite subsets is finite. It is closed under unions. So maybe we just need to require that the union of any two sets in the collection is also in the collection? Surely that'd be enough (I leave it for you as an exercise).

But is that really the right answer? Suppose that $X$ was infinite and we remove the set $\{x,y\}$, now $\{x\}$ and $\{y\}$ do not have their union in our collection, but certainly there's some $z$ and $\{x,y,z\}$ was not removed and contains both as well as $\{x,y\}$. So maybe closure under unions is not the right thing.

And this leads us to the definition of directedness. Recall that a partial order $(P,\leq)$ is *directed* if whenever $p,q\in P$, there is some $r$ such that $p\leq r$ and $q\leq r$. And I leave you the task to verify that if $\{X_\alpha\mid\alpha\in\Lambda\}$ is directed (under $\subseteq$), then it satisfies the definition.

Now you might think that it is an equivalent definition. Alas, it is not. Consider the following family of subsets of $\Bbb N$, let $p_n$ be the $n$th prime number, and let $A_n=\{p_n^k\mid k\in\Bbb N\}$; and now consider $X_n=A_n\cup\{k\in\Bbb N\mid k<n\}$. Then $\{X_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ is not directed, not linearly ordered, not anything. But its union is $\Bbb N$, and given any finite $F\subseteq\Bbb N$, there is some $n$ such that $F\subseteq X_n$, e.g. $n=\max F+1$.